# Custom attributes in WPF user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I want to add custom attributes to my user control such that the UserControl will then use that attribute when displaying (or turning on / off) various options

i.e.

```
<toolkit:UC_TitleBar title="My Application Title" showCloseButton="false" />
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need are [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx)

```
public class UC_TitleBar : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCloseButtonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowCloseButton", 
                                                    typeof(Boolean), typeof(UC_TitleBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
    public bool ShowCloseButton
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowCloseButtonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowCloseButtonProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //add dependency property
    public static DependencyProperty MyTestProperty;

    //init dependency property in static control constructor
    static MyControl()
    {
         var myTestPropertyMetadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, MyTestPropertyChanged);


                MyTestProperty= DependencyProperty.Register("MyTest",
                                                       typeof(string),
                                                       typeof(MyControl),
                                                       myTestPropertyMetadata );
    }

   //implement property 
    public String MyTest
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(MyTestProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyTestProperty, value);
        }
    }

   //using in xaml
   <MyControls:MyControl MyTest="dfdsf" />
```

read more about dependency properties in MSDN